# How to call powershell in c++ with no window

Tags: c++, powershell

I am using this to call powershell, but even if I use CREATE_NO_WINDOW, this code is a C&P from my previous system() call. But it doesnt work.
updated code (still not working):

```
LPWSTR PSPath = env(_TEXT("SystemRoot"));
LPWSTR TEMP2 = env(_TEXT("TEMP"));
LPWSTR HOMEDRIVE = env(_TEXT("HOMEDRIVE"));
LPWSTR PSPathexe = (_TEXT("%s\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -Executionpolicy bypass -File \"%s\\psscript.ps1\" -Filename psscript -Folderpath \"%s\\deployment\""),PSPath,TEMP2, HOMEDRIVE);
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

CreateProcess(NULL, PSPathexe, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `-WindowStyle Hidden` option?

Comment: yes, still not working. And I found a mistake, there was a system() call for powershell before. 
The code above does not even work =/

Comment: Initializing pointer to non-`const` with a literal is invalid as of C++11, the rule set that governs that bit. At least two of the `CreateProcess` arguments where you provide 0, don't accept 0, according to Microsoft's documentation, which is the rule set that governs *that* bit. Do **read the documentation**.

Answer (score 1):

First, the line

```
LPWSTR command=(_TEXT("powershell.exe -Executionpolicy bypass -File \"%deploy%\\psscript.ps1\" -Filename psscript -Folderpath \"%HOMEDRIVE%\\deployment\""));
```

… has three serious problems:

- `LPWSTR` is a Microsoft macro that expands to `wchar_t*`, while the initializer reduces to a literal, which is an array of `const` characters. This removal of `const` was deprecated in C++98 already (the first C++ standard), and was removed – it's now **invalid** – in C++11.
- `_TEXT` is a Microsoft macro that adds a prefix `L` to the literal if the macro symbol `_UNICODE` is defined. It was once part of a scheme to provide compatibility with Windows 95, until the Layer for Unicode was introduced in the year 2000. We are now **16 years after this became obsolete**, and to top it, you will just get a compilation error if you don't define `_UNICODE`, because you're not using the scheme everywhere, as required.
- The `%HOMEDRIVE%` in the string is a command interpreter syntax for expanding an environment variable. I'm not 100% sure, only 99.8% or thereabouts, but as far as I can recall `CreateProcess` doesn't have that functionality.

The type problem (first bullet point) can be fixed by using a local array, e.g.

```
wchar_t command[] = L"notepad.exe";
```

Note that `CreateProcess` requires this to be writeable. So even with a compiler that accepts the original declaration you'd be off in **Undefined Behavior** land, with code potentially trying to modify a literal.

The environment variable problem can be fixed by expanding that variable prior to constructing the command string. For this I would use `std::wstring`. It helps with concatenation and such.

---

Then, the call

```
CreateProcess(NULL, command, NULL, NULL, NULL, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

… provides `NULL` for the argument where the process and thread handles are returned, and for the argument specifying startup info. That's not going to work. Read the documentation.

---

Tips:

1. If you try out `CreateProcess` with some simpler task in mind, e.g. running Notepad, you can learn how to call it properly with less effort.
2. You might find `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx` preferable to the basic `CreateProcess` (disclaimer: I haven't checked whether they support windowless execution, but it's likely they do).